# How to add text after the last comma in a string? (.Net Version of RegEX)

Tags: .net, regex

I need to add the text "MS" without quotes, after the last comma within a string.

**Examples:**

- 123 Main Street, Townsville, 210-319

**becomes**

- 123 Main Street, Townsville, MS 210-319

**and**

- 123 Main Street, West Street, Townsville, 210-319

**becomes**

- 123 Main Street, West Street, Townsville, MS 210-319

Can you offer a RegEx solution using the net framework?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead to check for the last comma.

```
(?<=,)(?=[^,]*$)
```

Replace the matched boundary with `MS` or `<space>MS` .

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cW4qQ3/3)

Comment: Thanks to you both, I chose Avinash's answer because it was first, although I'm sure both work equally well. Take care

Answer (score 1):

or use this pattern

```
(.*,)
```

and replace w/

```
$1 MS
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cW4qQ3/4)